# NPE with WP7 .NET Silverlight custom control after navigating

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I've implemented a custom control that is basically a button panel at the bottom of the screen.  Our application has several views and most of them are going to reference this custom control.

I've created some methods that affect the display properties of some UIElements in the custom control but these cease to work after navigating away from the default view because all of the UIElements become null.  Can someone explain why this happens and what I can do to prevent this issue?  All of my work will have been for nothing if this is only usable in one view!  Here's some code to be of use:

My custom control:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ControlBar">
  <Grid x:Name="ControlPanel" Margin="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1">
    <Canvas x:Name="ControlPanelButtonStack">
      <Button x:Name="GoButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="8" Visibility="Visible"/>
      <Button x:Name="StopButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="70" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="8" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The method that is causing trouble:

```
public void DisableGoButton()
{
   Button goButton = this.GetTemplateChild("GoButton") as Button;
   goButton.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

The above method will work in the MainPage.xaml but as soon as we navigate to a different view (call it SettingsPage.xaml) it fails because goButton will always be null.  In all of these views the custom control is referenced in the XAML like such:

```
<controlBar:ControlBar x:Name="ControlBar" Margin="0,698,0,0" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Is there anybody who has had this issue that knows how to work around it?  Thanks!